# "costs of generating electricity" VS "costs of electric power generation"

Tags: prepositions

> 1. to reduce the costs of generating electricity.
> 2. to reduce the costs **of** electric power generation.
> 3. to reduce the costs **for** electric power generation.

I have two questions:
 (1)is 2) equal in meaning to 1) and which is clearer and used more often.
 (2) which preposition should I opt for, **for** or **of**

Comment: They're all fine, as would be all versions with singular ***cost***, those with just ***power*** instead of ***electric[al] power***, and other variations. There's really nothing here worth "learning", unless you're interested in the fact that [singular "cost" is more common.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+cost+of+electricity+generation%2Cthe+costs+of+electricity+generation&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20cost%20of%20electricity%20generation%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20costs%20of%20electricity%20generation%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Is there any difference between the plural form and the singular form?

Comment: In principle, yes (plural implies multiple contributory cost factors, singular implies lumping them all together into a "total cost"). But in practice, few people would ever consider things like that in most contexts. Really, I can't see that you're going to get anything useful out of this question - even if all you're doing is effectively asking us to "proofread" your text. There ***is*** no "single, unambiguously correct" answer, and most or all discussion about the merits or demerits of specific phrasing would just be *opinions*.

Comment: ...for what it's worth, *my* opinion is that plain [*reduce the cost of generation*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+cost+of+power+generation%2Cthe+cost+of+generation%2Cthe+cost+of+generating+electricity&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20cost%20of%20power%20generation%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20cost%20of%20generation%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20cost%20of%20generating%20electricity%3B%2Cc0) is short and to the point for most contexts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your context they read very slightly differently:

2 reads in a very slightly more general way than 1, suggesting also the costs to the environment and humanity as a whole, but that may only be to a British English speaker's ear.

3 suggests a narrowing, for example "For this project which is already over-budget, what can we do to reduce the costs for electric power generation". Otherwise the preposition "for" seems awkward.

Again all of them are fine, but 1 is simpler and reads better, but I'd expect to see 2 rather than 1 in a government communique, as it sounds more pompous.

Comment: Forgive me if I get this wrong. Why should be government communique be pompous? I mean it should be as accessible to the general public as possible, otherwise ordinary people may not know what the government is talking about.

Comment: The expression sounds more formal or official - rather than pompous!

Comment: Mike Philip - we're into the realm of personal opinion here. In a perfect world they wouldn't be, but in my experience they tend to be written in a house style which is harder to parse, with a tendency to use phrases which are intended sound impressive but contain no benefit of a simpler phrase. There are some gems on the internet but "High-quality learning environments are a necessary precondition for facilitation and enhancement of the ongoing learning process." is a good example.